# How do logical operators work with Promises in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, es6-promise

I am following a tutorial on promises and encountered the following use of promises with logical operators, which I can't quite understand. In the example below, there is a function `getJSON` returning a promise. And it is connected to an uninitialized variable `storyPromise` using `||` (logical OR??) operator repeatedly (`storyPromise = storyPromise || getJSON('story.json');`). I am not exactly sure what does it mean to `OR` an variable with a promise, especially at the beginning when the variable is `undefined`.

Can someone please help explain the logic/work flow for the line in question? How does a promise interplay with Boolean variables?

(I know very basic Javascript but not modern features such as promises)

```
var storyPromise;

function getChapter(i) {
  storyPromise = storyPromise || getJSON('story.json');

  return storyPromise.then(function(story) {
    return getJSON(story.chapterUrls[i]);
  })
}

// and using it is simple:
getChapter(0).then(function(chapter) {
  console.log(chapter);
  return getChapter(1);
}).then(function(chapter) {
  console.log(chapter);
})
```

The `getJSON()` function is defined as follows:

```
function get(url) {
  // Return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      // This is called even on 404 etc
      // so check the status
      if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resolve the promise with the response text
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        // Otherwise reject with the status text
        // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Make the request
    req.send();
  });
}

function getJSON(url) {
  return get(url).then(JSON.parse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that pick the value of storypromise if it is defined otherwise go for the calling the method getjson() and assign the value returned from there. 
This is a common practice in many other languages as well.
The operands of 'or' can be variables or methods.